# Run Current Junit Test in GWTTestCase

Tags: gwt, junit, tdd

I have a JUnit test that I run on one class, but I recently wrote an emulated version for GWT.  Since the specification is the same, I would like to use the same test case, but I want it to run in the GWT environment, which would typically be accomplished by extending GWTTestCase.

I really want to avoid any copy/paste nonsense, because there are likely to be added tests in the future, which I should not be burdened with copying later.

How can I import/inherit my standard unit test to be run as either a regular test case or a GWT test case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found the solution to this problem.

If you extend the original test with GWTTestCase, you can override getModuleName to return null.  This tells GWTTestCase to run as a normal pure java test (no translation at all).

You can then extend this test case with one that overrides getModuleName to return a module name, and the same tests will be run with translation.

Basically:

```
public class RegularTest extends GWTTestCase {

  @Override
  public String getModuleName() { return null; }

  public void testIt() {...}

}
```

...and the GWT version...

```
public class GwtTest extends RegularTest {

  @Override
  public String getModuleName() { return "some.module"; }

}
```

The downside to this is that it forces you to use JUnit3 style tests, which I find a little annoying, but it beats the alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no easy way .. But you can extract an interface of your junit test, gwt test case and junit test case implements this interface. You can create a third class for implementation,  all test call methods of gwt test case and junit test  are delegated to this implementation class.

```
public interface IRegularTest {
       public void testSomething();
       public void testSomething2();
}

public class RegularTestImpl implements IRegularTest {

      public void testSomething(){
         // actual test code
      }

      public void testSomething2(){
         // actual test code
      }

}

public class RegularTest extends TestCase implements IRegularTest {
      IRegularTest impl = new RegularTestImpl();

      public void testSomething(){
           impl.testSomething   
      }

      public void testSomething2(){
      }
}


public class GwtTest extends TestCase implements IRegularTest {
      IRegularTest impl = new RegularTestImpl();

      public void testSomething(){
           impl.testSomething   
      }

      public void testSomething2(){
      }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but this was the type of thing I'd like to avoid.  If I have to do this, it's pretty likely I won't want to add additional tests, when I know I need to.

Comment: I think you could not find a better solution than this one. If you could, I would be the first one who will upvote.

Comment: Found out if you extend GWTTestCase and override getModuleName to return null, it runs as a pure java test.